# Difficulty in finding the issue in my jQuery that's causing elements to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a nav menu that opens up with a menu inside when a specific button is clicked.

The functionality is as follows;

Click a button, the button turns into an 'X' close button, and the nav bar expands to show a menu. You can then either click a link in the menu or click the 'x' close button and the navigation menu will close.

This all works great - the issue I'm having is that when a link is clicked, the menu closes, and then if you try and open the menu again by clicking on the open button the menu has disappeared and doesn't come back.

In addition, I'm still very new to jQuery and I know my code is probably a horrible mess.

Here's my jQuery. Forewarning: I'm sorry & yes I am ashamed

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
$('.mobile-nav-icon').click(function() {
    $('.fa').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
    $('.nav').toggleClass('hundredvh', 'noheight');
});


$('.linx').click(function(event){
$('.nav').removeClass('hundredvh');
$('.fa').addClass("fa-bars");
$('.fa').removeClass("fa-times");
$('.menu').addClass("noheight");
});
```

And lastly, [here's a jsFiddle of the issue I'm having](https://jsfiddle.net/connorv/y34p2ayL/).

Comment: I'm clicking on button to open, then I'm clicking Twitter, menu closes, then I can open that menu again. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is your last line, you are adding a height of 0 to your menu which is basically hiding it... remove it and it works fine... remove $('.menu').addClass("noheight"); on ('.linx').click function

Comment: I'm getting this error when I click a link {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: The menu disappears only when you click Touring or Contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

`$('.menu').addClass("noheight");`

You are setting your `.menu` which has your links in it to have no height (and the `.nav` class has `overflow: hidden;`) then never removing that class. I do not see the purpose of adding it here so you could just remove adding this class altogether.

See this update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y34p2ayL/3/)

Comment: I see. I can't believe I missed this... Was going crazy for hours over this one. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this - Set a height on .nav in CSS & my issues were solved.